# Problema al actualizar registros en la base de datos

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mysqli

El código me devuelve los valores que están registrados en la base de datos, pero a la hora de modificar los datos y pulsar el botón de guardar no se ejecutan los cambios.

**RegistroDelegaciones.php**

```
<?
 $conect = new mysqli("localhost", "mpadioce_horacio", "MPADT-2018", "mpadioce_MPA");
 $sql = "SELECT * from InformacionGeneral";
 $resultado=mysqli_query($conect,$sql);

 while($fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc ($resultado)){
?>     
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Delegacion"]?></td>   
        <td><?php echo $fila["Parroquia"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Correo"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Tios_Rensponsables"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Telefono_TioRes"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Asessor_Espiritual"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Fecha"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Tios_apoyo"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila["Telefono_TioApoy"]?></td>
        <td><a href="actualizarprueba.php?idg=<?php echo $fila["Id_General"]?>"><center><img src='img/edit.png' width="40" height="40" class='img-rounded'></center></td>
        <td><a href="EliminarDelegacion.php?idg=<?php echo $fila["Id_General"]?>"><center><img  src='img/delete.png' width="40" height="40" class='img-rounded' with:10px;/></a></center></td>
      </tr>   
      <?php
 }
 ?>
```

**actualizarprueba.php**

```
<?
 $conect = new mysqli("localhost", "mpadioce_horacio", "MPADT-2018", "mpadioce_MPA");
 $Id_General=$_GET['idg'];
 $sql = "SELECT * from InformacionGeneral WHERE Id_General='$Id_General'";
 $resultado=mysqli_query($conect,$sql);
 $fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc ($resultado);
?>     

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
  <title>Administrador</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>BIENVENIDO SR. HORACIO DEL VALLE</h1>
  <p>ADMINISTRADOR DEL SITIO</p> 


            <form action="ejecutaactualizar.php" method="POST name="actualizar">
            <input type="hidden" name="Id_General" value="<?php $Id_General?>">
            <h4>Delegacion</h4>  <input type="text" name="delega" value="<?php echo $fila['Delegacion'] ?>"><br>
            <h4>Parroquia</h4>  <input type="text" name="parroquia" value="<?php echo $fila['Parroquia'] ?>"><br>
            <h4>Correo</h4>  <input type="email" name="correo" value="<?php echo $fila['Correo'] ?>"><br>
            <h4>Tios Responsables</h4>  <input type="text"  name="tiosr" value="<?php echo $fila['Tios_Rensponsables'] ?>"><br>
            <h4>Telefono Tio Responsables</h4>  <input type="text"  name="tel0" value="<?php echo $fila['Telefono_TioRes'] ?>"><br>
            <h4>Asesor Espiritual</h4>  <input type="text"  name="asesor" value="<?php echo $fila['Asessor_Espiritual'] ?>"><br>
            <h4>Fecha</h4>  <input type="date"  name="fecha" value="<?php echo $fila['Fecha']?>"><br>
            <h4>Tios de Apoyo</h4>  <input type="text"  name="apoyo" value="<?php echo $fila['Tios_apoyo'] ?>"><br>
            <h4>Telefono Tios Apoyo</h4>  <input type="text" name="tel1" value="<?php echo $fila['Telefono_TioApoy'] ?>"><br>

                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-success btn-primary">
            </form>


</body>
</html>
```

**ejecutaactualizar.php**

```
<?php
    $conect = new mysqli("localhost", "mpadioce_horacio", "MPADT-2018", "mpadioce_MPA");

    $IDGENERAL=$_POST['Id_General'];
    $DELEGACION=$_POST['delega'];
    $PARROQUIA =$_POST['parroquia'];
    $CORREO =$_POST['correo'];
    $TIOSRESPONSABLES =$_POST['tiosr'];
    $TELEFONOTIO =$_POST['tel0'];
    $ASESOR =$_POST['asesor'];
    $FECHA =$_POST['fecha'];
    $TIOSDEAPOYO =$_POST['apoyo'];
    $TELEFONOTIOSAPOYO =$_POST['tel1'];

    $sql="UPDATE InformacionGeneral SET Delegacion='$DELEGACION',Parroquia ='$PARROQUIA',Correo='$CORREO',Tios_Rensponsables='$TIOSRESPONSABLES',Telefono_TioRes='$TELEFONOTIO',Asessor_Espiritual='$ASESOR',Fecha='$FECHA',Tios_apoyo='$TIOSDEAPOYO',Telefono_TioApoy='$TELEFONOTIOSAPOYO' WHERE Id_General='$IDGENERAL'";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conect,$sql);  

    if ($resultado==null) {
        echo "Error de procesamieno no se han actuaizado los datos";
                    echo '<script>alert("ERROR EN PROCESAMIENTO NO SE ACTUALIZARON LOS DATOS")</script> ';
                    header("location: RegistroDelegaciones.php");

                    echo "<script>location.href='RegistroDelegaciones.php'</script>";
                }else {
                    echo '<script>alert("REGISTRO ACTUALIZADO")</script> ';

                    echo "<script>location.href='RegistroDelegaciones.php'</script>";
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué error te da, si te da alguno? ¿Qué es lo que hace o no hace para que digas que no actualiza?

Comment: Jose Luis, llevas pocos dias en el sitio, asi que te recomiendo que vuelvas a leer [ask]. Cosas como _Ayuda!_, poner el título en mayusculas, comentarios superfluos... no ayudan a resolver tu problema e incluso dan una imagen negativa a otros usuarios que pueden verse menos inclinados a ayudarte. Es un consejo, espero que no te lo tomes a mal. Un saludo y suerte con tu pregunta.

Comment: Tu código no blinda el resultado de las consultas por lo que pierdes cualquier mensaje de error que te estén generando y, además, ni escapas el contenido de los datos obtenidos por GET/POST ni usas consultas preparadas y mezclas la interfaz OOP con la de llamadas a funciones (`mysqli_query()` en vez de `$conect->query()`). Hay que hacer muchas modificaciones a tu código para empezar a obtener los mensajes de error que nos podrían ayudar a solucionarte el problema. ¿Estás disponible para ello?

Comment: @JaviMollá no me arroja ningun error, cuando ejecuto me dice que el dato a sido actualizado pero cuando verifico no lo hace.

Comment: @Pikoh muchas gracias por tus recomendaciones, si soy nuevo aquí, así que tendre en cuenta tus recomendaciones, muchas gracias

Comment: @OscarGarcia ya modifique el error de POST, amm estoy mejorando mis funciones  y nada, me sigue igual

Comment: Te ayudaría a resolverlo en dos partes. Primero te propondría cambios en el código para obtener los mensajes de error que no estás controlando y en segunda instancia arreglaríamos el problema que lo produce. Para empezar, ¿En el log de error del servidor web te están apareciendo mensajes de error o advertencias? Para continuar, ¿Cuándo tendrías disponibilidad para hacer los cambios?

Comment: tengo disponibilidad ahorita mismo @OscarGarcia ok deja checo si me manda algun error

Comment: @OscarGarcia respecto a tu primera pregunta es si me arroga un error a la hora de conectarme al servidor?

Comment: No, me refiero a si aparecen mensajes en el log del servidor web (el `error.log` del apache). Por norma general las advertencias y otros mensajes ya no van al navegador por defecto. Yo ahora no puedo ayudarte (creo que vivimos en franjas horarias diferentes), pero en cuanto pueda te propongo los cambios necesarios para detectar el problema.

Comment: @ Oscar garcia, ok ya entendi, deja checo el log del servidor entonces, esta bien en cuanto puedas me ayudas vale, un saludo

Comment: ¿Has podido probar el código que te he propuesto?

Comment: ya lo solucione pero implementare el código que me proporcionaste para estructurarlo de mejor manera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A parte de la comilla que te faltaba en el atributo `method` del formulario (`<form action="ejecutaactualizar.php" method="POST" name="actualizar">`, reportado por [@Dubas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/18345/dubas) en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/194533/18608)), agrego lo siguiente:

El problema más grave que encuentro en tu código es que no escapas las cadenas correctamente antes de agregarlas al SQL, por lo que una simple comilla podría provocar que la sintasis de tu SQL sea incorrecta y, peor aún, puede sufrir los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

Para solucionarlo podemos hacer uso de consultas preparadas (ver siguiente punto) o bien usar [`mysqli::real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysqli.real-escape-string) para escapar previamente el contenido de la variable de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
/* Establecemos la conexión */
$conect = new mysqli(
  "localhost",
  "mpadioce_horacio",
  "MPADT-2018",
  "mpadioce_MPA"
);

/* Escapamos las cadenas correctamente antes de agregarlas al SQL: */
$IDGENERAL = $conect->real_escape_string($_POST['Id_General']);
$DELEGACION = $conect->real_escape_string($_POST['delega']);
$PARROQUIA = $conect->real_escape_string($_POST['parroquia']);
$CORREO = $conect->real_escape_string($_POST['correo']);
$TIOSRESPONSABLES = $conect->real_escape_string($_POST['tiosr']);
$TELEFONOTIO = $conect->real_escape_string($_POST['tel0']);
$ASESOR = $conect->real_escape_string($_POST['asesor']);
$FECHA = $conect->real_escape_string($_POST['fecha']);
$TIOSDEAPOYO = $conect->real_escape_string($_POST['apoyo']);
$TELEFONOTIOSAPOYO = $conect->real_escape_string($_POST['tel1']);

/* Ahora pueden concatearse al SQL de manera segura: */
$sql = "
    UPDATE InformacionGeneral
    SET
        Delegacion = '$DELEGACION',
        Parroquia = '$PARROQUIA',
        Correo = '$CORREO',
        Tios_Rensponsables = '$TIOSRESPONSABLES',
        Telefono_TioRes = '$TELEFONOTIO',
        Asessor_Espiritual = '$ASESOR',
        Fecha = '$FECHA',
        Tios_apoyo = '$TIOSDEAPOYO',
        Telefono_TioApoy = '$TELEFONOTIOSAPOYO'
    WHERE Id_General = '$IDGENERAL'
";
/* Convierto tu llamada a mysqli_query a OOP */
$resultado = $conect->query($sql);

/* Si $resultado vale null hubo un problema con la consulta (sintaxis, etc) */
if ($resultado === null) {
    /* Las cabeceras deben ser lo primero en ser enviadas, después
        va el contenido. Aún así para depurar un error SQL lo mejor
        es no forzar la redirección aún para ver el error con tranquilidad */
    /*header("location: RegistroDelegaciones.php");*/
    echo "Error de procesamiento no se han actualizado los datos:";
    /* Toda salida de texto al navegador debe pasar por htmlspecialchars() */
    echo '<pre>', htmlspecialchars($conect->error), '<pre>', PHP_EOL;
    /*echo '<script>alert("ERROR EN PROCESAMIENTO NO SE ACTUALIZARON LOS DATOS")</script> ';
    echo "<script>location.href='RegistroDelegaciones.php'</script>";*/
} else {
    echo '<script>alert("REGISTRO ACTUALIZADO")</script> ';
    echo "<script>location.href='RegistroDelegaciones.php'</script>";
}
```

He cambiado ligeramente el código cuando se detecta un error con la consulta para que no pase a la siguiente página. Con esta modificación podrás leer el mensaje de error SQL con tranquilidad para depurarlo.

Fíjate el uso de [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) para escapar también las cadenas de caracteres que serán enviadas al navegador y [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) para las cadenas que se agreguen a una URL. Esto es especialmente importante en el siguiente script PHP para protegerte de ataques [XSS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting):

```
<?php
$conect = new mysqli(
    "localhost",
    "mpadioce_horacio",
    "MPADT-2018",
    "mpadioce_MPA"
);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM InformacionGeneral";
$resultado = $conect->query($sql);
if ($resultado === null) {
    die('ERROR SQL:<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($conect->error) . '<pre>');
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?= htmlspecialchars($fila["Delegacion"]) ?></td>   
        <td><?= htmlspecialchars($fila["Parroquia"]) ?></td>
        <td><?= htmlspecialchars($fila["Correo"]) ?></td>
        <td><?= htmlspecialchars($fila["Tios_Rensponsables"]) ?></td>
        <td><?= htmlspecialchars($fila["Telefono_TioRes"]) ?></td>
        <td><?= htmlspecialchars($fila["Asessor_Espiritual"]) ?></td>
        <td><?= htmlspecialchars($fila["Fecha"]) ?></td>
        <td><?= htmlspecialchars($fila["Tios_apoyo"]) ?></td>
        <td><?= htmlspecialchars($fila["Telefono_TioApoy"]) ?></td>
        <td><a href="actualizarprueba.php?idg=<?= htmlspecialchars(urlencode($fila["Id_General"])) ?>"><center><img src='img/edit.png' width="40" height="40" class='img-rounded'></center></td>
        <td><a href="EliminarDelegacion.php?idg=<?= htmlspecialchars(urlencode($fila["Id_General"])) ?>"><center><img  src='img/delete.png' width="40" height="40" class='img-rounded' with:10px;/></a></center></td>
      </tr>   
<?php } ?>
```

NOTA: Te recuerdo que la etiqueta de apertura de PHP es `<?php` y no `<?`. Esta última sólo está disponible si se activa la opción [`short_open_tag`](http://www.php.net/ini.core#ini.short-open-tag) en el `php.ini`, por lo que podrías tener problemas en gran cantidad de servidores que no tengan o no te permitan habilitarla. La etiqueta `<?=` está siempre disponible desde PHP 5.4.

Por último, el formulario en sí:

```
<?php
$conect = new mysqli(
    "localhost",
    "mpadioce_horacio",
    "MPADT-2018",
    "mpadioce_MPA"
);
/* Si no se recibe el idg por GET terminamos la ejecución */
if (empty($_GET['idg'])) {
    die('Debe proporcionar un "idg"');
}
/* No es necesario ni recomendable usar variables intermedias */
/*$Id_General = $_GET['idg'];*(
$sql = 'SELECT * from InformacionGeneral WHERE Id_General = ?';
/* Preparamos la consulta */
$consulta = $conect->prepare($sql);
/* Asignamos al primer ? el valor de idg pasado por GET */
$consulta->bind_param('s', $_GET['idg']);
/* Obtenemos los resultados */
$resultado = $consulta->get_result();
/* Ahora podemos obtener el registro */
$fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
/* Si devuelve false es porque no se encontró el registro */
if ($fila === false) {
    die('No se encontró el registro solicitado');
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title>Administrador</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>BIENVENIDO SR. HORACIO DEL VALLE</h1>
  <p>ADMINISTRADOR DEL SITIO</p>
  <!-- Que no se te olvide la comilla tras el post -->
  <form action="ejecutaactualizar.php" method="POST" name="actualizar">
    <input type="hidden" name="Id_General" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($fila['Id_General']) ?>">
    <h4>Delegacion</h4>
    <input type="text" name="delega" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($fila['Delegacion']) ?>"><br>
    <h4>Parroquia</h4>
    <input type="text" name="parroquia" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($fila['Parroquia']) ?>"><br>
    <h4>Correo</h4>
    <input type="email" name="correo" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($fila['Correo']) ?>"><br>
    <h4>Tios Responsables</h4>
    <input type="text" name="tiosr" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($fila['Tios_Rensponsables']) ?>"><br>
    <h4>Telefono Tio Responsables</h4>
    <input type="text" name="tel0" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($fila['Telefono_TioRes']) ?>"><br>
    <h4>Asesor Espiritual</h4>
    <input type="text" name="asesor" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($fila['Asessor_Espiritual']) ?>"><br>
    <h4>Fecha</h4>
    <input type="date" name="fecha" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($fila['Fecha']) ?>"><br>
    <h4>Tios de Apoyo</h4>
    <input type="text" name="apoyo" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($fila['Tios_apoyo']) ?>"><br>
    <h4>Telefono Tios Apoyo</h4>
    <input type="text" name="tel1" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($fila['Telefono_TioApoy']) ?>"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-success btn-primary">
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias bro ya me actualiza pero te agradeceria mucho a que me  ayudes a mejorar mi codigo probare lo de escape de las cadenas y como evitar inyecciones sql

Comment: Puedo ayudarte a mejorar el código, sólo tienes que hacer las preguntas correctas ;). Voy a incluir en mi respuesta más información acerca de cómo blindar tu código ante errores, pero que sepas que sufres un problema grave de seguridad en tu código. Se trata de [CSRF](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), que permitiría que una página externa maliciosa "inyecte" modificaciones en tu página.

Comment: Una respuesta de libro! Enhorabuena!

Answer (score 2):

A simple vista en tu  pagina "actualizarprueba.php" esta incorrecto

```
   <form action="ejecutaactualizar.php" method="POST name="actualizar">
```

Falta una comilla doble despues de POST por lo que no se estaria ejecutando la acción POST y por tanto en la pagina siguiente los valores de `$_POST` no se estan obteniendo.

Debiera ser

```
   <form action="ejecutaactualizar.php" method="POST" name="actualizar">
```

Por otra parte deberias mejorar la seguridad para evitar inyecciones de codigo. Como minimo usar la función `mysql_real_escape_string` para no usar los datos de entrada del POST tal cual. (Pero esto es otra batalla sobre la que deberias pensar para reorganizar todo tu código)

El problema tambien podria ser derivado de la configuración del servidor. Si no esta activado el modo AutoCommit deberas ralizar un commit de las operaciones de modificación. Asi mismo controlar los errores con funciones de rollback. (Esto se ejecuta sobre el recurso de conexión)

Ejemplo (muy simple):

```
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());

// operaciones SQL

mysql_query("COMMIT", $connection);
```

Tambien si se usa el driver MySQLI como objeto (PH5/7) tienes directamente el método de [commit](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.commit.php) y de [rollback](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.rollback.php)

Comment: El enlace es correcto (navega a la pagina al realizar el submit) pero si no es correcto el atributo "method" de la etiqueta form los datos se envia por defecto por GET y no por POST por lo que no te rellena las variables $_POST. Revisa si el caso es correcto o si es una errata en el ejemplo que has puesto y que por favor deberias corregir para que te podamos dar la mejor solución

Comment: Por favor revisa mi respuesta. El problema no es el url de enlace, si no el atributo "method" que no esta bien cerrado en el form. He completado mi respuesta con estas anotaciones y espero que sea mas clara.

Comment: Ok. Cosas como una comilla perdida son dificiles de visualizar y es facil que pasen desapercibidos. En todo caso tus comentarios han servido para darle una segunda vuelta a mi respuesta y completar un poco el ejemplo a fin de ser mas claro. No es necesario que borres nada.

Comment: muchas gracias, ya modifique lo de la comilla del POST y aun me sigue el error, amm voy a implementar lo que me dices del AutoCommit

Comment: amigos sigo con el problema, mire el error.log y no me marca errores, alguien podría darme otra solución por favor